# SQL Query Join Posts with number of followers per post and all photos per post?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, postgresql, relational-database

Simple Question. More Complex Answer. How can I join my Posts table with my `Posts_Pictures` table with my `Users_Favorites` table to get all the posts, the `numberOfFollowers` for each post, and finally if the user is following that specific post?

Here are my tables:

**Posts:**

postId **INT**

fullName **VARCHAR**

etc...

**Users:**

userId **INT**

etc...

**Post_Pictures:**

postPictureId **INT**

image **VARCHAR**

idx **INT**

post_id **INT**

---

**Users_Favorites:**

userFavoritesId **INT**

user_id **INT**

post_id **INT**

---

This is what I have so far and it returns everything except the total number of followers per post and the pictures associated with each post:

```
SELECT p.*
     , uf.`userFavoritesId` 
  FROM Posts as p
  LEFT 
  JOIN Users_Favorites as uf
    ON p.`postId` = uf.`post_id`
 ORDER 
    BY p.created DESC;
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score -1):

Try running only the below sub-query to see if the joins come back as you expect. If it looks ok, try running the entire thing.

This would return the postid from posts, the postpictureid from post_pictures, and it's counting the number of times for each post_id that there is a userfavoritesid that is not null.

Providing additional info or some sample data will make it much easier to provide a better answer.

```
select postid
    , postpictureid
    , sum(case when userfavoritesid is not null then 1 else 0 end) as numberoffollowers
from
    (
    select p.postid
        , p.fullname
        , pp.postpictureid
        , pp.image
        , pp.idx
        , uf.userfavoritesid
        , uf.user_id
        , uf.post_id
    from posts as p
    left join post_pictures as pp
        on a.postid = pp.post_id
    left join users_favorites as uf
        on pp.post_id = uf.post_id
    ) as x
;
```

Comment: Happy to elaborate if the downvoter has an issue with this answer. I applied the table names and types provided by the user to construct a query in line with their question.